# What is the rationale for High Integrity C++ rule 7.2.1

Tags: c++

[High integrity C++ rule 7.2.1](https://www.perforce.com/resources/qac/high-integrity-cpp-coding-standard/declarations), "Use an explicit enumeration base and ensure that it is large enough to store all enumerators" requires that enumerations and scoped enums are defined with a base (size)

e.g.
// Compliant

```
enum E1 : int8_t {a,b,c};
enum class E2 : int32_t {a,b,c};
```

// Non-Compliant

```
enum E3 {a,b,c};
enum class E4 {a,b,c};
```

Excluding forward declarations where the size cannot be determined by the compiler, we cannot understand the rational behind this requirement. We feel that forcing the developer to specify the size more likely than not gets in the way of potential compiler optimizations. What benefit is derived by insisting the programmer makes a decision when the compiler can determine this?

What is the rationale behind this rule?

Comment: Makes catching serialization mistakes easier. Other than that I've got nothing.

Comment: From your link: The underlying type of an unscoped enumeration is implementation defined, with the only restriction being that the type must be able to represent the enumeration values

Comment: That particular ruleset does tend to go out of its way to minimise use of constructs with implementation-defined behaviour. A general rationale for that is minimising code that works with one implementation but breaks with another.  In this case, the rule ensures that the enumerated type has a predictable size - which may matter if doing binary I/O of values (a file written on one system can be read on another), or if code changes behaviour based on size of a type. IMHO it is better to write code that is unaffected if variable's size changes between implementations, rather than fixing sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Well, it depends ...™"*

If, in your particular situation, you have no particular reason to care how many bits your compiler may choose to use to describe your `enum`, then ... *well ...* "you have no reason to care!"

But if you might need to be certain that some underlying data representation (a binary record, for example ... an in-memory structure ...) uses "a certain known number of bits," *then* you care.

While I generally agree with many of the principles in these *"high integrity™"* guidelines, I'm not so sure about this particular section.  *Absent other ruling considerations to the contrary,* I'm not terribly inclined to tell the compiler what it must do.  "If I don't have *reason* to care, then I don't care."

Answer (score 0):

If you specify it yourself then:

- You know exactly how much disc space program is gonna need.
- If done right (e.g. proved by math), your calculations of needed space cannot be worse than those made by compiler, thus unnecesary compiler operations => compilation is longer (incomprehensible for smaller programs).
- Extra protection against cross-platform errors (data types size is not predetermined, purely compilator/os based).

Comment: point 3 is not quite true. This will still be vulnerable to endian differences

Comment: "If done right" - is exactly why we need things like Hit C++ so I would not be asking the question.